# Falling in love during Ramadan

Tags: ramadan, love

The devil is chained during Ramadan but some of us still fall in love while fasting. Does this mean that it is true love? And is it better for us to get married during Ramadan rather than other months?

Comment: Devil is chained but not our nafs (desires). In ramadhan the people will do the sin because of there nafs. And Devil make an attitude of doing sin. so he will do sin in this month also.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue in falling in love with anybody in any month of Islam. 
.. What do you mean by first line.. falling in love while fasting?.. if you mean you looked at somebody and now feeling that you're in love with him/her?..
If this is so... then its mean dont' look at anybody lustfully. That's sin...

because love is not something as a famous saying.. "love at first sight"..

this is not something you are going to spend the whole life with a person you just seen.. definitely you need time to understand other person.. so falling in love is totally a kind of fake feeling... 
but If you still have liked somebody, and your intentions are to marry with him/her, then Its good. Islam promotes love and peace. but this all should be in the circles of `shariat`

Your second question.. YES.
You can get married during Ramazan. And rather if you get a chance to get married in Ramadan, you must choose it. Ramazan is a month full of ALLAH's blessings. And you can make love with your wife/husband in Ramazan as well. But only after you complete fast(after `Aftaari`).